# Showing res.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
    const Express=require('express');
    const fs=require('fs');
    const app =new Express();
    // app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    //     res.send("Hello I am at Home");
    // })
    // app.post("/",(req,res)=>{
    //     res.send("hello i am at end point");
    // })
    const tours=JSON.parse(
        fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/data.json`,'utf-8')
    )
    app.get('/api',(res,req)=>{
        res.json({
            status:"success",
            data:{
                tours:tours
            }
    
        })
        console.log("server running")
    })
    app.listen(8000);
```

**Showing `res.json` is not a function.**

Why it is showing this error? I saw a tutorial in which the code run successfully, but I am getting error?

Comment: you switched the position of the parameters in the callback function. The first parameter should be the request the second the response ... `app.get('/api' (req, res) => {...}`

Answer (score 0):

**try this code for the route**

```js
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        status:"success",
        data:{
            tours:tours
        }

    })
    console.log("server running")
})
```

**It should be `(req, res)` not `(res, req)`**

Answer (score 0):

your callback parameter is reversed.
it should be :

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
... 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Always you have to pass req first in your callback because after req only we will get response.Like below

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
-------
})
```